# Control checkout parameter in TFS Build with git

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild, build-definition

We’re running TFS 2013 with a Git repository.

Cloning the repository (with quite a bit of history) for each build takes about 20 minutes on our build server (>2GB repository).

How can we change the parameters for the clone in the build definition to fetch only the latest state with no history, i.e.

```
git clone --depth 1 ...
```

?

Do we need a custom build definition?
Any built-in functionality we can use?

Any hints much appreciated!

Comment: 1). You can reduce the download time but un-checking the Clean Repository in the Build definition, step 1.1       2)  Your repo looks big, if it contains binary files or other stuff which is not source, you could consider cleaning that out.  3) The build definition does not have any parameters for depth, so yes, you would need to change the "Pull sources from Git repo" activity.

Comment: Cheers! 1 - Can't do, we're updating assembly infos so getting conflicts if we attempt that.   2 - We should, but it's scary to retro-modify the repository.   3 - Any hints on how to do that? Never tried to change an activity

Comment: 2. You will always do the binary cleaning in a local repo.  You can then push that up to a new repo on the TFS, and remove the connection to the old repo, so that you keep the old git server repo unmodified as a backup.

Comment: 3.  Modifying the build there is not that fun, the best guidelines are from Ewald Hofman http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/20/customize-team-build-2010-e28093-part-1-introduction.aspx and the VS ALM Rangers guide https://vsarbuildguide.codeplex.com/.  I am not sure why they have a separate activity for that instead of just calling the git command using a powershell script.  You would have to go in and look.  Or, it could be wise to wait for TFS 2015, and use the new build system there, it is much simpler.

Comment: Oh boy, sounds like we'll better wait for TFS-2015! It's already RC anyways..  Many thanks for the detailed info!

Answer (score 0):

FWIW - we switched off the clone option and just pull latest changes for each built. To undo the changes performed on the build server after pulling (adjust assembly info/version, etc.) we went with a **custom post build step** to `git reset` and `git clean`.

This way we won't have any conflicts when pulling the latest changes next time round..